# laravel migration dropForeign not working

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have:

```
$table->dropForeign(['type_id']);
```

but when I run migration I getthe following error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'ingredi
>     ents_type_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `ingredients` drop foreign key `ingredients_type_id_foreign`)

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the key isn't there or it has different name.

Log into your database, do **SHOW CREATE TABLE ingredients;** and check if the key is there and what it's name is.

Comment: Yes, type_id exists in the table

Comment: Not the type_id, the key ingredients_type_id_foreign.

Comment: Can you post a migration that you used to create a table?

Comment: ingredients_type_id_foreign does not exist, i haven't use that.
This is the way i created this column:
$table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->after('name');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: Then when you do SHOW CREATE TABLE ingredients; you should see a row that creates a foreign key. It will contain the name of the foreign key you need to pass to dropForeign()

Comment: it is type_id, no doubt. what confuses me is why he is looking for ingredients_type_id_foreign when i specified type_id

Comment: type_id is the name of a column. foreign keys get different names assigned automatically by laravel - {table}_{column_name}_foreign. Can you paste what "show create table ingredients" gives you?

Comment: Thanks jerdzej.kurylo , the problem was that the migration firstly run partially, and removed foreign keys. on other runs there were no foreign keys set so it was looking for default one.

Comment: Thanks @jedrzej.kurylo . I got same issue. Your cmd helped me. In past, I've renamed my table, but not changed foreign so it till be old name.